# Is there any way to run susy or singularity with libsass?

Tags: css, sass, singularitygs, libsass, susy

I like susy, I like Singularity. Is there a way to make those two work with libsass or if not are there any grid frameworks like the two which I can use with libsass (using node-sass in my case)?

Comment: If you downvote, please explain.

Comment: This is off topic: asking to find an off-site resource, library, etc.

Comment: Bourban Neat and Jeet should work...

Comment: Susy Two is ready for libsass, as soon as they add support for maps. Susy One should work without problems, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: @EricMSuzanne: How would I go about installing susy with libsass?

Comment: Download the source from GitHub (or use Bower to download/manage it for you).

Comment: I am curently using Libsass, susy and gulp... just wrote a jolly long thread about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541188/getting-libsass-gulp-susy-to-work-together/28541189#28541189

Answer (score 3):

Yes! As of [v2.2.1](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/changelog/#jan-14-2015) **susy** supports **libsass** 3.0.2+.

Answer (score 1):

No. I think [Neat](http://neat.bourbon.io/) is compatible with libsass.

Answer (score -1):

You can use libsass to compile within CodeKit.

Comment: Not using CodeKit. I'm on linux. But how would that make singularity work?