# Getting Libsass Gulp Susy to work together

Tags: gulp, susy, libsass

I have just spent the last 5 days playing with this and trying to get the following to work together:

```
¬ Libsass
¬ Susy
¬ Gulp
```

But now I have it working I have just gone for `45s` to `700ms` This is something I feel I should share.

Initial Problem

**Gulp**

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('./frontend/sass/style.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            'require':'susy'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/www/css'))
});
```

**Sass**

```
@import "susy";
```

**Inital Error**

```
[23:58:08] Starting 'sass'...

stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
Error: file to import not found or unreadable: susy
Current dir: C:/var/www/www.hutber.com/frontend/sass/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complete working setup

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "~3.8.10",
    "gulp-sass": "~1.3.2", //this installs libsass for us
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "~1.3.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "~0.6.6",
    "susy":"~2.2.2"
}
```

**Gulp sass Task**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var handleErrors = require('../util/handleErrors');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css');

//libsass
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('./frontend/sass/style.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: [
                './node_modules/susy/sass' //required for sass
            ]
        }))
        //.pipe(minifyCSS()) //move to prod settings
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./app/www/css')))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/www/css'))
});
```

**Sass**

```
@import "susy";

$susy: (
    global-box-sizing: border-box,
    use-custom: (rem: true),
    columns: 12,
    gutters: (1/4),
    debug: (
        image: hide,
        color: rgba(#66f, .25),
        output: background,
        toggle: top right,
    )
);
```

**Errors**

You will need to do the following to avoid the `may only compare numbers` error when running the task

**Update node-sass's package.json**

I had to update libsass's dependency as follows:

```
gulp-sass 1.3.1 
  ¬ node-sass 2.0.0-beta
     ¬ libsass 3.1.0-beta - This needed updating to libsass 3.1.0-beta.2
```

The above will become redundant as soon as `node-sass` update their dependency to use the newest `libsass`

**Last Step**

Then inside my sass use `(1/4)` rather than just `1/4`. This will force it to be treated as a number. Bug taken from https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/590

You should be able to run gulp `sass` without any errors.

Comment: It not work `@import "susy";`   it good work `@_import "susy";` Why?